# Print Perl Regex Matches

Tags: regex, perl, printing

In the program I'm working on, I'm attempting to take in a txt file, then print the bits of txt contained in a pair of quotation marks.

Assuming I've taken in the txt file and put it into an array with each line as an array element this is what I was assuming would work, but alas no luck:

```
txt file contents:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur "adipisicing elit"
sed "do" eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut "labore et dolore" magna aliqua

CODE:
foreach(@arr)
{
    print $1 if /("*")/g;
}

Output: 
""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ...
foreach (@arr) {
    print $1 for /(".*?")/g;
}
 ...
```

Comment: This worked perfect!
It must be ("+.*"), otherwise my version of perl prints the "Nested quantifiers" error message.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand is, why the . (dot) meaning 'any character except newline' forces it to print correctly?

Comment: @user1783150 in `".*?"` `*` matches any char zero or more times, and `?"` tells regex to match until first double quote (non greedy matching).

Comment: Ah! Some how I missed that issue! I ran into problems with having two strings on one line, the `?`sorted that out though.

Now I've got to work out a way to print out all matches found in a line of text.


There must be a neater way than `if` statements iterating though `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc until one is empty?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach(<DATA>) {
    print $1 if /(".*")/;
}

__DATA__
txt file contents:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
consectetur "adipisicing elit"
sed "do" eiusmod tempor incididunt
ut "labore et dolore" magna aliqua
```

Comment: with what extension should i save this file and how should i run it ?

Comment: @aelor: I used __DATA__ section. You should use a file handler have a look to samples [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).